# Access UIViewController inside ContainerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, interface-builder, container-view

I have the following setup:

`SplitViewController` as rootController.

Detail part is first

`ViewController` with `View` > `ContainerView` (later, `View` will have `ImageView`, but that is not the issue here).

The `ContainerView` has segue (embed) to another view controller (`NavigationController`).

This is graphically represented in IB as:

[image: Layout in IB]

Now the thing is I want to access the `NavigationController` from rootController (eg `SplitViewController`). I was unable to navigate down the hierarchy of "subViews" and so.

Is there some convenient way to get hold of the `NavigationController`?

Without the `ViewController` (together with ContainerView), I was able to access it like:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
// now i have the controller, i can delegate to it or use it in any other way:
splitViewController.delegate = (id) navigationController.topViewController;
```

Comment: Did the code provided in my edited answer work for you?

Comment: @NoilPaw hi, I haven't had the time for it yet, but I'm going to try it out tomorrow. Thanks for the answers, don't worry they will be unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the NavigationController, you could pass it upwards (delegate methods) to your subclass of UISplitViewController and store a reference there.

You could add a `@property (MySplitViewController *) delegate;` your MyContentView and set it to the splitviewcontroller. When the segue is fired, you could then do the following:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowNavigationController"])
    {
        UINavigationController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        [self.delegate setNavigationController:controller];
    }
}
```

Edit: If you want to stick to your code, you could do something like this:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *container = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [container.childViewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id) navigationController.topViewController;
```

In that case you should really include some error handling.

Comment: I don't have access to NavigationController to pass a delegate to id. My question is how to get hold of the NavigationController. Once I have its instance, I now how to proceed.

Comment: @Savannah: If i understand correctly, you could use the segue, which adds the navigationcontroller to bind it to your splitviewcontroller.

Comment: @Savannah: Please have a look at my edited answer. If i should add more detail, please let me know.

Comment: @Savannah I added another way of setting the delegate.

Comment: well, after a bit of tweaking, your Segue solution works wonders! Thanks a lot!